# Joining Multi-dimensional Array Using column_stack() Method in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

***Code***

import numpy as np

n5 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

n6 = np.array([[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80]])

print(n5)

print(n6)

np.column_stack((n5,n6)

***On executing the above query I get the following output:***

[[1 2 3 4] 
[5 6 7 8]] 
[[10 20 30 40]
[50 60 70 80]]

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 20, 30, 40],
[ 5,  6,  7,  8, 50, 60, 70, 80]])

***Expected Output:***

array([[
[ 1, 10],
[ 2, 20],
[ 3, 30],
[ 4, 40]],

```
    [[ 5, 50],
    [ 6, 60],
    [ 7, 70],
    [ 8, 80]]])
```

***I got the expected output using the following code:***

***Code:***

np.stack([n5,n6], axis=2)

I want the expected output using the column_stack() method. Can you help me understand why am I not getting the correct output using the column_stack() method?

Comment: You have 2 (2,4) arrays, and the result is (2,8).  That's 2*4 columns, axis 1.  `stack` made a (2,4,2) joining the arrays on a **new** trailing axis.

Comment: Read the docs, for 2d arrays, column_stack is the same as hstack.